# Не подтягиваются стили меню в wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Всем привет, возникла такая проблема, подключаю функцию wp_nav_menu в верстку, но стили из css файла не подгружаются. Должно быть так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у меня вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стили подключены правильно, так как вся остальная страница сайта отображается. Так же в админке я задала произвольным ссылкам css класс, но стили все равно не подтягиваются как надо.
в header.php пишу следующий код

```
 <?php 
                    wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                             'theme_location' => 'Header menu', 
                             'menu' => 'navbar-nav',          
                            'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav',
                            'menu_id' => 'main_menu_id',
                            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse menu__center ml-lg-4',
                       
                            )
                        );
                ?>
```

Comment: И что за стили?

Comment: которые в исходниках

Comment: Надо писать  не "Стили подключены правильно,", а код подключения. А вообще F12 всё расскажет.

Comment: Ну это ответило на все мои вопросы, тогда все ясно (нет)! Если у Вас все стили в одном файле и они отработали на всей странице, кроме меню, то наверное у меню немного другая структура.